# Rails.cache.fetch caching in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

Using Rails.cache.fetch like below is caching even in my development environment (with caching turned off):

```
@boat_features = Rails.cache.fetch("boat_features", expires_in: 10.minutes) do
  BoatFeature.all
end
```

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 8):

That's normal. That sort of caching isn't turned off in development. In a previous app where this was a problem we used the memory store and then added a middleware that did `Rails.cache.clear` after every request.

Something like

```
config.middleware.use ClearCache
```

in development.rb

and then your ClearCache middleware should look something like

```
class ClearCache
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  ensure
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
end
```

In Rails 3.2 there's also `ActiveSupport::Cache::NullStore`

Comment: The nullstore can be added to development.rb with config.cache_store = [:null_store]

Comment: @frederick - pretty sure that isn't true - config/environments/development.rb has "perform_caching" turned off by default

Comment: Perform caching is unrelated to Rails.cache.fetch

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I worked around a lot then came up with this simple solution. In your development configuration file `config/environments/development.rb` add these settings

`config.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store`